# Problems with facebooks conceal library

Tags: java, android, facebook, encryption, io

I'm having issues with reading decrypted data from conceal. It looks like I can't correctly finish streaming.
I pretend there is some issue with conceal, because of when I switch my proxyStream (just the encryption part) to not run it through conceal, everything works as expected. I'm also assuming that writing is ok, there is no exception whatsoever and I can find the encrypted file on disk.

I'm proxying my data through contentprovider to allow other apps read decrypted data when the user wants it. (sharing,...)

In my content provider I'm using the openFile method to allow contentResolvers read the data

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        String name = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        File file = new File(name);
        InputStream fileContents = mStorageProxy.getDecryptInputStream(file);
        ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream stream = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1]);
        PipeThread pipeThread = new PipeThread(fileContents, stream);
        pipeThread.start();
        return pipe[0];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I guess in the Facebook app Facebook android team could be rather using a standard `query()` method with a byte array sent in `MediaStore.MediaColumns()` which is not suitable for me because of I'm not only encrypting media files and I also like the approach of streams better.

This is how I'm reading from the Inpustream. It's basically a pipe between two parcelFileDescriptors. The inputstream comes from conceal and it is a FileInputstream wrapped into a BufferedInputStream originaly.

```
static class PipeThread extends Thread {
    InputStream input;
    OutputStream out;

    PipeThread(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
        this.input=inputStream;
        this.out=out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
            int len;

            try {
                while ((len=input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }

                input.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Exception transferring file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried other methods how to read the stream, so it really shouldn't be the issue.

Finally here's the exception I'm constantly ending up with. Do you know what could be the issue? It points to native calls, which I got lost in..

```
Exception transferring file
com.facebook.crypto.cipher.NativeGCMCipherException: decryptFinal
        at com.facebook.crypto.cipher.NativeGCMCipher.decryptFinal(NativeGCMCipher.java:108)
        at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherInputStream.ensureTagValid(NativeGCMCipherInputStream.java:126)
        at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherInputStream.read(NativeGCMCipherInputStream.java:91)
        at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherInputStream.read(NativeGCMCipherInputStream.java:76)
```

EDIT:
It looks like the stream is working ok, but what fails is the last iteration of reading from it. As I'm using buffer it seems like the fact that the buffer is bigger then the amount of remaiming data is causing the issue. I've been looking into sources of conceal and it seems to be ok from this regard there. Couldn't it be failing somewhere in the native layer?
Note: I've managed to get the decrypted file except its final chunk of bytes..So I have for example an incomplete image file (with last few thousands of pixels not being displayed)

Comment: I would be interested to see the code that actually writes the file out as well. 

``while ((len=input.read(buf)) > 0) {}``

is not a correct way of reading from a stream, but rather 

``while ((len=input.read(buf)) != -1) {}``

The last iteration of the stream is important since it checks the integrity of the file, so you shouldn't leave that out.

Comment: This exception is usually thrown when there's a mismatch between the written file and the read file, i.e. there is actually either a file tampering case or the wrong file is being read. This is a security exception, so that's why I'm curious about storageProxy and the impl of the writing code.

Comment: Actually I've been seeking for an issue there, but sadly this is not the root of my problem..
I have tried to use exactly the code you adviced before, but it still does not work..I then started to doubt my code completely and have tried to use `ByteStreams.copy(input, out);` instead..Still the same exception..

Comment: Right, the writing code is also important in that case. Since many things could potentially cause this, for instance, the whole of the original data was not written out or the entity that was supplied is not the same as the one read back by the app code. If you could revise your example with more detailed code or submit a bug report on the github page, I could help you out resolving your issue.

Comment: Actually there is a bug report pretty similar to this post:) I've post it to both sites..
Shouldn't the data be written ok, as I'm not getting eny exception while writing them? 
Speaking about the entity..What does that thing suppose to mean exactly? Docs are pretty sparse about it. I wasn't sure, so I just have it there as a final static value...
I can post whole my code, since it's rather a proof of concept library and not incorporated into any larger project yet.
I have pushed it to bitbucket..
https://simekadam@bitbucket.org/simekadam/securedfileprovider.git

Comment: here is the issue on github https://github.com/facebook/conceal/issues/24

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was resolved in https://github.com/facebook/conceal/issues/24. For posterity's sake, the problem here is that the author forgot to call close() on the output stream.

Answer (score 4):

From my little experience with conceal, I have noticed that, only the same application that encrypts a file could decrypt it successfully irrespective whether it has the same package or not. Be sure to put this in mind

Comment: You are right. Conceal uses sharedPreferences to store the necessary keys. Therefore if you clean app data or use another device, you will not be able to decrypt.