# Decrypt file with facebooks conceal library

Tags: android, facebook, encryption, io

I'm trying to use conceal facebook library to encrypt and decrypt some audio files.
So the encryption phase has no problem but the subsequent phase of decryption always ends with the following error:

```
com.facebook.crypto.cipher.NativeGCMCipherException: decryptFinal
   at com.facebook.crypto.cipher.NativeGCMCipher.decryptFinal(NativeGCMCipher.java:108)
   at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherInputStream.ensureTagValid(NativeGCMCipherInputStream.java:126)
   at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherInputStream.read(NativeGCMCipherInputStream.java:91)
   at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherInputStream.read(NativeGCMCipherInputStream.java:76)
```

This is my code:

```java
public class Main extends Activity {

private Button btnEncrypt, btnDecrypt, btnPlay, btnStop;
private final String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
private File file;
private String media;
private NativeCryptoLibrary mNativeCryptoLibrary;
private Crypto crypto;
private keyChain key;
private Entity entity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnEncrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt);
    btnDecrypt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecrypt);

    mNativeCryptoLibrary = new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary();
    key = new keyChain();

    crypto = new Crypto(key, mNativeCryptoLibrary);

    if (!crypto.isAvailable()) {
        Log.e("ERROR: ", "crypto not available!");
        return;
    }

    media = mediaPath+"/example.mp3";
    file = new File(media);
    entity = new Entity("TEST");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OutputStream fileStream, outputStream;
            try {
                final byte[] encrypt = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(media));
                // encrypt
                outputStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(fileStream, entity);
                outputStream.write(encrypt);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CryptoInitializationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyChainException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FileInputStream fileStream;
            OutputStream out;
            try {
                fileStream = new FileInputStream(media);
                InputStream inputStream = crypto.getCipherInputStream(fileStream, entity);

                out = new FileOutputStream (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/decrypt.mp3");
                int read;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CryptoInitializationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyChainException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

I've found this post [Problems with facebooks conceal library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906953/problems-with-facebooks-conceal-library) but i still can't solve my problem.

Comment: DecryptFinal will fail if the mac does not match. I think the problem may be because you're recreating the crypto object and the keychain every time onCreate is called. this will cause the key to be reset, so it wont be able to decrypt the file you just encrypted.

Are you getting an error when the activity gets recreated or an error when you press the decrypt button?

Comment: No, the problem occurs even if i run first encryption and after decryption of the file without exiting from activity, so it is recreated. 
The only error that arises is the one written above.